# Tkinter listboxes and canvas won't scroll together

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I want the following layout in TkInter:
4 listboxes next to eachother, a canvas next to them, filled with buttons (one button for every element in the listboxes)

The problem is, that the canvas can be scrolled with the listboxes, also  on it's own, but even higher than the point where it has content, which means, you can scroll it to the very top, but the listbox belonging to it won't even move, and they are de-synched already. So question is, how can I give a point for the scrolling where it can not go higher?

The code I have is the following:

```
from Tkinter import *

def Scroll2Gether(*args):
  list1.yview(*args)
  list2.yview(*args)
  list3.yview(*args)
  list4.yview(*args)
  ButtonLine.yview(*args)

master = Tk()
EndLayer = Canvas(master)
scroll = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=Scroll2Gether)
UpperLayer = Frame(EndLayer, bg = '#000fff000')

list1 = Listbox(UpperLayer, bg = "#B2B2B2",width = 60)

list3 = Listbox(UpperLayer, bg = "#B2B2B2",width = 60)

list4 = Listbox(UpperLayer, bg = "#E5E5E5",width = 60)

list2 = Listbox(UpperLayer, bg = "#E5E5E5",width = 60)

Framm = Frame(UpperLayer, bg = "#ffa300", width = 30, )

Address1 = Label(list1, text = "OWNER1", bg= "#E5E5E5",width = 60,font=("Helvetica", 8,"bold"))
Address2 = Label(list2, text = "OWNER2", bg= "#B2B2B2", width = 60,font=("Helvetica", 8,"bold"))
Address3 = Label(list3, text = "MailDL", bg= "#E5E5E5", width = 60,font=("Helvetica", 8,"bold"))
Address4 = Label(list4, text = "ExpirationDate", bg= "#B2B2B2", width = 60,font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold"))

ButtonLine = Canvas(Framm, bg = "#E5E5E5", width = 30)

Address1.pack(side = TOP)
Address2.pack(side = TOP)
Address3.pack(side = TOP)
Address4.pack(side = TOP)

list1.pack(side = LEFT, fill = "y")
list2.pack(side = LEFT, fill = "y")
scroll.pack(side="right",fill="y")
list3.pack(side = LEFT, fill = "y")
list4.pack(side = LEFT, fill = "y")
Framm.pack(side=LEFT)
ButtonLine.pack(side = BOTTOM)

UpperLayer.pack()
EndLayer.pack()

x = 0

photo=PhotoImage(file="email.gif")

for i in ("qwertzuiopasfghjklyxcvbnm"):
 i = Button(text="Mail")
 i.config(image = photo, width = 20, height = 20)
 Button_Window = ButtonLine.create_window(1, 22+x, anchor = NW, window = i)
 x = x+26
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I found out that it makes no sense to group 3 columns, so I created lines which are canvas and created canvases in them for every input in a loop.